# Some basic questions regarding proportion terminology

Tags: ratio

A question posed in a review assignment:

1. Find the fourth proportional to $4,6$ and $8$

The answer is 12. Thus I guess we were supposed to solve $\frac{4}{8}=\frac{6}{12}$. So when the numbers are listed like this, is it common to assume that this means we are solving the proportion $4:8 \iff 6:12$? Or is this a poorly worded question? Perhaps it's standard terminology I'm not aware of

Comment: I have never heard this terminology, and would not have guessed that meaning.  That said, it seems that people [do use it](https://atozmath.com/RatioAndProp.aspx?q=6_FP&q1=6%60FP%604%2C6%2C8&do=1#tblSolution)